# Store child class's name in database column in polymorphic association - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a class, say, Car from which I have inherited classes Black and Red as follows:

```
class Car::Black < Car
end

class Car::Red < Car
end
```

Now, there is another class, say, CarPurchase which has many Cars of both varieties. The associations are as follows:

```
# In Black and Red models:
has_many :car_purchases, as: :purchasable, dependent:destroy

# In CarPurchase model:
belongs_to :purchasable, polymorphic: true
```

Now I'm trying to save the CarPurchases like this:

```
black_car.car_purchases.new()   # black_car is an object of class Car::Black
```

My database has a column called purchasable_type. The problem is that records are saved with purchasable_type 'Car' and not 'Car::Black'. I tried saving the purchasable_type explicitly also while creating record. No luck. Help please.

Comment: I think that is correct...You are using STI and polymorphic...in that case the base class type should be set...Check out Polymorphic associations section for more details...http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations

Comment: I did see that link before. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check this out...This can be of some help http://www.archonsystems.com/devblog/2011/12/20/rails-single-table-inheritance-with-polymorphic-association/

Comment: Thanks again. Still not helping..

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  class Black < Car; end
  class Red < Car; end
end
```

The reason it stores `Car` is defined in [`ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation#replace_keys`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_polymorphic_association.rb#L14) 
Excerpt:

```
def replace_keys(record)
  super
  owner[reflection.foreign_type] = record.class.base_class.name
end
```

and [`ActiveRecord::Inheritance::ClassMethods::base_class`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L94) 
Excerpt:

```
def base_class
  unless self < Base
    raise ActiveRecordError, "#{name} doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord"
  end

  if superclass == Base || superclass.abstract_class?
    self
  else
    superclass.base_class
  end
end
```

So if `Car` is an `abstract_class` then it will store `Car::Black` other wise the `base_class` will resolve to `Car`. Making `Car` an `abstract_class` will not lose most of the magic e.g. `Car::Black` still knows it's `table_name`.

**Caveat** using `Car` as an `abstract_class` means it cannot be instantiated directly.

For Example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  class Black < Car
  end
end 
Car::Black.base_class.name 
#=> Car
Car::Black.table_name
#=> "cars"
Car.new 
#New Car record
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
Car::Black.base_class.name 
#=> Car::Black 
Car::Black.table_name
#=> "cars"
Car.new
#=> NotImplementedError: Car is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is not about saving records under Cars table but under CarPurchases table. In cars table full class name is being saved. But in car_purchases table, purchasable_type is Car and not Car::Black.
Also, the above mentioned example is not what I'm trying to implement. It is just to explain the problem. I'm trying to solve something similar.

Comment: @KeerthanaRaghavan Okay I understand the situation now. See Update for potential work arounds